# Microsoft Sync Framework

Tags: .net, sql-server, wcf, microsoft-sync-framework

I've got a central SQL server database. My solution has a WCF service responsible for synchronizing data with clients running SQL Server or SQL Server Express.

The service uses Microsoft Sync Framework and it works well, but the Sync Framework requires a direct connection to my client's server, and clients that are running SQL Server Express may not have a static IP address to let my application locate them.

How can I overcome this problem? Does Sync Framework have an intermediate service that can exchange datasets of changes on both server and client? Or can I use Sync Framework to get datasets of changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams like you should be running the sync framework from your clients.

Yes they have provider implementations that use WCF so that the provider is running in the WCF service which accesses the central database and the provider that the sync coordinator users is just a proxy.